# Declaring a Type variable that must be a subclass - Dart

Tags: dart

Kotlin code:

```
Class<? extends Model> someType();
```

I want to do the equivalent in Dart where I can **declare** a variable that stores a class that must extend from the Model class.

So far, I only know how to declare a variable that stores a generic class in a Dart variable via:

```
Type someType;
```

But I want "someType" to only be Types/Classes that extend from the Model class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart `Type` objects are not generic. There is only one `Type` class, and no way to compare them for subtyping. The `Type` objects are also fairly useless for anything else.

**You should probably not be using `Type` objects at all.**

They are rarely what you need because they are so completely useless in most situations. If you are not using `dart:mirrors`, I recommend no using `Type` objects at all.

So, *why* do you want to store a `Type` value to begin with?
Is there some way you could store it as a *type variable* instead?

Say, you need to know the type in order to create a list of that type. `Type` objects can't do that, but a proper generic type variable can be used.

Consider having a class like;

```dart
class MyType<T> {
  const MyType();
  /// Perform [action] with [T] as type argument.
  R callWithType<R>(R Function<T>() action) => action<T>();
  
  // Checks and casts.
  bool isInstance(Object o) => o is T;
  T cast(Object o) => o as T;
  T safeCast(Object o) => o is T ? o : null;

  // Subtyping checks.
  bool operator >=(MyType other) => other is MyType<T>;
  bool operator <=(MyType other) => other >= this;
  bool operator <(MyType other) => other >= this && !(this >= other);
  bool operator >(MyType other) => this >= other && !(other >= this);
  bool operator ==(Object other) => 
      other is MyType && this >= other && other >= this;
  int get hashCode => T.hashCode;

  // Whatever other operations you want.
}
```

Then you can use *that* kind of "type representation object" instead of a `Type` object, and you can actually use it for practical operations. You can then also ask for a `MyType` object for a restricted type:

```dart
MyType<Model> modelType; // Only `MyType` objects for `Model`s
// or 
void withType<T extends Model>(MyType<T> type, ...) ...
```

You can still only do things that are supported by type variables. You can't create a new instance of `T` or look up static members of the class, those *only* work using the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

[Abstract classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) cannot be instantiated directly, and therefore any variable typed with an abstract class could only be initialized with a subclass. This *might* suit your purpose.